# Angular syntax error in VS 2012

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2012

I am newbie to Angular 2 but have some understanding on Angular 1 & TypeScript (worked extensively with JavaScript/JQuery but not TypeScript or Angular 1).

While exploring Angular 2, I followed few articles & tried to read & follow samples related to Angular 2 in Visual Studio 2012 with a web application. Somehow, VS doesn't recognize Angular syntax & throws several errors in .ts file. Sample code below which throws errors. However VS do recognize TypeScript & Angular 1 syntax in HTML. I tried to find solution on my own but failed.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '< h1 > Hello {{name}}< / h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Any help would be benefit me to explorer it further.

```
Error   1   Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.   D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 1   1   TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   2   ';' expected.   D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 1   27  TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   3   Unexpected character "@".   D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 3   1   TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   4   Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.   D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 3   1   TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   5   Could not find symbol 'Component'.  D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 1   10  TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   6   Could not find symbol 'from'.   D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 1   22  TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   7   Could not find symbol 'Component'.  D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 3   2   TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   8   Build: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.    D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 1   1   TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   9   Build: ';' expected.    D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 1   27  TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   10  Build: Unexpected character "@".    D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 3   1   TypeScriptHTMLApp
Error   11  Build: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.    D:\TypeScriptHTMLApp\TypeScriptHTMLApp\Component.ts 3   1   TypeScriptHTMLApp
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Total 11 errors. like unexpected character@, unexpected token.. blah..blah. Updated original question with errs

Comment: Which version of typescript are you running?

Comment: TypeScript 1 as am running VS 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2012 is too old and it might only support TypeScript 1.0 which does not support decoractors (notice the `@...`).

Check [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2564). VS 2012 TS version has stopped at `TypeScript 1.0.1`.

Use a newer version, VS2015 or VS2017 or even VSCode. Also you are not bound to using only Visual Studio. You can use whatever you want - WebStorm, IntelliJ, Sublime, Atom, ... .

Regarding VS, usually you can install the [TypeScript SDK](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links) of the corresponding version you are using.

Other IDEs, like WebStorm and IntelliJ have their own plugins to provide the design time support for editing TypeScript.

I would recommend you to stop looking for Angular2 and move to learning the latest Angular version (v4 at this time of writing). This framework has evolved fast and changed dramatically. Don't expect that any of the earlier materials, somewhere around the middle of year 2016, will help you meet current requirements.

Comment: Would you recommend VS Code instead to explorer Angular?

Comment: VSCode, VS, ... - any modern editor that has complete support. This is only to edit your code. Running the Angular app in development is usually done using the `angular-cli` (eg: simply `ng serve`), which is building using TypeScript and bundles everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators has been introduced in TypeScript version 1.5 with ES7/ES2016 as mentioned in What's new of TypeScript's official documention [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-5.html).

Decorator support for ES3 was also introduced in TypeScript version 1.7 as per [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html) document.

Make sure you are following correct combination of TypeScript with ES to build your solution.

Note: you can verify your ES version at Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> Project.